# Configuring Duktape 2.5.0 for use under MacOSX (Catalina)

Tags: duktape

I am wanting to build Duktape to run under MacOSX.
The instructions [here](https://duktape.org/guide.html#compiling) say to run the supplied configuration tool at tools/configure.py
There are different instructions [here](https://github.com/svaarala/duktape/blob/master/doc/duk-config.rst) saying to run tools/genconfig.py

Both scripts fail with

```
import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

There are files in the distribution ending in .yalm but no file of that name.

Any help would be much appreciated.  I have not been able to find any support forum for Duktape.

Answer (score 0):

I've moved on from here.  Just compiled Duktape as a single source file with my application and all is good.  Resolved.